# EPPlus Date Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, epplus

I need to format the date in Excel while writing in the Excel sheet.
It should display this format "MM/dd" but when click on this then formula bar show the complete date "MM/dd/yyyy".

For reference I have attached the screenshot as well. Please check and suggest how I can achieve this in EPPlus Code.

[image]

I have tried the following code but no luck:

namedWorksheet.Cells["E4"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "M/dd/yyyy";

namedWorksheet.Cells["E4"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").Substring(0,4);

Comment: What's actually in E4?

Comment: I need to add same date in E4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this issue.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL")

                {
                    DateTimeFormat = { YearMonthPattern = "MM/dd" }
                };

                namedWorksheet.Cells["G4"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.YearMonthPattern;
                var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
                var date = dateAndTime.Date;
                namedWorksheet.Cells["G4"].Value = date;
```